# Auto identify mime types in wildfly10

Tags: utf-8, wildfly, mime-types, wildfly-8, wildfly-10

To suppport all UTF-8 characters we have added in Servlet filter

```
servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=" + "UTF-8");
servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(servletResponse.getCharacterEncoding());
```

because of this it sets the content type as "text\html" for all file types and for css also and browser denies to load it css with error on browser as.

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

But above works in jboss 6
I tried setting

```
<servlet-container name="default">
    <jsp-config mapped-file="false" development="true"/>
    <websockets/>
    <mime-mappings>
        <mime-mapping name="css" value="text/css"/>
        <mime-mapping name="msi" value="application/x-msi"/>
    </mime-mappings>
</servlet-container>
```

in the standalone-full.xml but this does not work. How does it automatically identify the file content types?

Comment: You don't need to do this - the default encoding is UTF-8.  I'd remove it all as the server should figure it out for you.

Comment: @stdunbar if i remove this then it fails to save utf-8 character as it modifies that character to something else

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet filter is really not the best answer *to support all UTF-8 characters*, as you noticed, this choice is weird but I will not discuss it because it is not your question.

So, if you need your servlet filter to not interact with other contents than `text/html`, just use a **servlet filter url-pattern**.

For instance, you could have a servlet filter definition like this:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>MyServletFilter<filter-name>
   <filter-class>[...]</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       [...]
   </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>MyServletFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Of course, you need to check that this pattern complies with your directory structure and other means to access your dynamic `text/html` contents.

Therefore, resources like http://myserver.com/myapp/myservlet/staticcontent/file.xls will not be altered by your specific filter.